# Python, use option variable as file name

Tags: python, variables, csv, argparse

I am trying to use a Python option/variable as a basis for the filename.csv file I will be using in the script.

Here is my code:

```
def get_args():
    '''This function parses and return arguments passed in'''
    # Assign description to the help doc
    global hostname
    global username
    global password
    global file
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--hostname', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--username', default='root', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--password', default='(&653hE@lU')
    hostname = args.hostname
    username = args.username
    password = args.password
    args = parser.parse_args()
    file = hostname.csv
```

I get the following error when running it:

```
./4collect.py --hostname bar 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./4collect.py", line 82, in <module>
    get_args()
  File "./4collect.py", line 67, in get_args
    parser.add_argument('--file', default=format(args.hostname)).csv
AttributeError: '_StoreAction' object has no attribute 'csv'
```

Comment: The code sample could not produce the error you show.  `.csv` is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the `csv` attribute of a variable named `hostname`, which of course doesn't exist, because `hostname` is just a string and strings don't have a `.csv` attribute.

If you are trying to create a filename by appending `.csv` to the *value* of hostname, you need somethingl ike:

```
file = '%s.csv' % hostname
```

Or:

```
file = hostname + '.csv'
```

Also, you would need to call `parser.parse_args()` *before* accessing `args.hostname`.